# Second Level Cache for Entity Framework 6. 1 any commercial, supported library?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, caching

I am looking for **stable library** second level cache for entity framework 6. 1 with support (updates).

It is for existing product, so I am not allowed to change every query ( so solutions like http://entityframework-plus.net/ is not allowed in my project).

**Do you know any library for second level cache of Entity Framework 6. 1 ?**

(yes, I know than EF has own cache, but it is only first level - entity)
I reviewed most of open source projects and they don't fit to my project.

Have a nice day
Grzegorz Pawluch

Comment: Have yóu checked my list here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2014/02/entity-framework-6-sql-server-compact_28.html ?

Comment: @ErikEJ  Yes, I have.  Thank you for response. Library Second Level Cache for Entity Framework 6.1 ( https://efcache.codeplex.com ) is very close my goal. What worries me about the library is  it was not updated since 2014 year. I am looking something mature and with updates -  commercial library is allowed. Could you suggest me something? Best regards from Poland!

Comment: @ErikEJ please check response above

Comment: This http://entityframework-plus.net/ ?

Comment: It looks almost perfect, but it requires changing whole my application. I am not allowed to do this ;/ - @ErikEJ

Comment: You have too many constraints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any existing Cache supporting fully what you want.

Most third party libraries become unsupported due to the complexity and time to invest.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

Perhaps you should open an [issue](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues) on our site or contact me directly so that we could discuss your requirements?